# NexusDB for each loop / substitute

Tags: sql, database, loops, nexusdb

I need a little push up.
I have a temporary table created from a select.

Now I need to go through that table and for each record in that table I need to do insert to other table with some values from this temporary tables.

Anyway I can't figure out any way how to do it in NexusDB.

Simply I want to do this in nexusdb sql:

```
foreach(record in table1){
  insert into table2 (columns) values record.id, record.name ... etc.
}
```

I hope it does make sense to you guys and I look forward to some beautiful ideas of yours.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NexusDB does not need "foreach", you can do it like this:

```
insert into temp1 (field_2, field_3) (SELECT field_2, field_3 FROM temp2)
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I did this first, but it didn't work, so maybe I was doing something wrong ...